# How to use session on Google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, session, authentication

I'm building an application using Google app engine with python, and I'm stuck with making sessions. Is there any app that already does that for app engine? Thank you.

Comment: You can now use webapp2 sessions, see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737008/google-app-engine-getting-sessions-working-with-python-2-7)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I recommend [gae-sessions](http://github.com/dound/gae-sessions/wiki).  The source includes demos which show how to use it, including how to integrate with the Users API or RPX/JanRain.

Disclaimer: I wrote gae-sessions, but for an informative comparison of it with alternatives, read [this article](http://github.com/dound/gae-sessions/wiki/comparison-with-alternative-libraries).

Comment: David, if it ever became possible it would be wonderful to see [itsdangerous](http://pythonhosted.org/itsdangerous/) added to the comparison chart with gae-sessions.